# Unable to delete WordPress user

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have one user in a WordPress site with username "admin9".

I'm unable to remove that user. Every time I try to delete it from WordPress, it shows a message saying that it was deleted successfully. But after that it shows the user again.

I have also tried to delete it from the database using phpmyadmin. But the same thing happens.

Comment: you are not capable to delete that user.your role is not allow to delete that user

Comment: Spelling correction and make question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure there is no such script present within code which creates user "admin9" on every page load(script added within init action which checks if user not present then programmatically create that respective user). Because if user is removed then there must be some script that may be creating that user programmatically.